# Getting error in LocationManager

Tags: android

I have been trying to get current address without mentioning latitude and longitude implicitly inside the code but by using LocationManager using GPS

iam getting only one error in LocationManager line in the below program:

```
     package com.example.admin.getcurrentlocation;


        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Locale;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.content.ContentResolver;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.DialogInterface;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
        import android.location.Address;
        import android.location.Geocoder;
        import android.location.Location;
        import android.location.LocationListener;
        import android.location.LocationManager;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.provider.Settings;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.ProgressBar;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

            private LocationManager locationMangaer=null;
            private LocationListener locationListener=null;

            private Button btnGetLocation = null;
            private EditText editLocation = null;
            private ProgressBar pb =null;

            private static final String TAG = "Debug";
            private Boolean flag = false;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


                //if you want to lock screen for always Portrait mode
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo
                        .SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

                pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
                pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                editLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLocation);

                btnGetLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);
                btnGetLocation.setOnClickListener(this);

                locationMangaer = (LocationManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                flag = displayGpsStatus();
                if (flag) {

                    Log.v(TAG, "onClick");

                    editLocation.setText("Please!! move your device to"+
                            " see the changes in coordinates."+"\nWait..");

                    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
       <--------------Error in this line------------->
     locationMangaer.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10,locationListener); 

                } else {
                    alertbox("Gps Status!!", "Your GPS is: OFF");
                }

            }

            /*----Method to Check GPS is enable or disable ----- */
            private Boolean displayGpsStatus() {
                ContentResolver contentResolver = getBaseContext()
                        .getContentResolver();
                boolean gpsStatus = Settings.Secure
                        .isLocationProviderEnabled(contentResolver,
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (gpsStatus) {
                    return true;

                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            /*----------Method to create an AlertBox ------------- */
            protected void alertbox(String title, String mymessage) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("Your Device's GPS is Disable")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setTitle("** Gps Status **")
                        .setPositiveButton("Gps On",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // finish the current activity
                                        // AlertBoxAdvance.this.finish();
                                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(
                                                Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
                                        startActivity(myIntent);
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // cancel the dialog box
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }

            /*----------Listener class to get coordinates ------------- */
            private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

                    editLocation.setText("");
                    pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Location changed : Lat: " +
                                    loc.getLatitude()+ " Lng: " + loc.getLongitude(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String longitude = "Longitude: " +loc.getLongitude();
                    Log.v(TAG, longitude);
                    String latitude = "Latitude: " +loc.getLatitude();
                    Log.v(TAG, latitude);

            /*----------to get City-Name from coordinates ------------- */
                    String cityName=null;
                    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(),
                            Locale.getDefault());
                    List<Address>  addresses;
                    try {
                        addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc
                                .getLongitude(), 1);
                        if (addresses.size() > 0)
                            System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                        cityName=addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    String s = longitude+"\n"+latitude +
                            "\n\nMy Currrent City is: "+cityName;
                    editLocation.setText(s);
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider,
                                            int status, Bundle extras) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is my Logcat.

```
 Process: com.example.admin.getcurrentlocation, PID: 3006
        java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
        at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:606)
        at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:885)
        at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:469)
        at com.example.admin.getcurrentlocation.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:77)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5269)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21556)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)




Manifest File:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admin.getcurrentlocation">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: @Hari you floating in this http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Post your manifest as well.

Comment: I added both permissions in manifest file but still getting the same error check the manifest file posted above

Comment: @Hari What is your target sdk version ?

Answer (score 1):

**Looking like you missing to add below permission in your manifest.**

As GPS location provider requires this permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

put these in your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Already added still same error... Does it matter with the Android studio versions ...Right now am using 1.5.1

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers mention, you have to request the permissions in your manifest file.
But, if you support Android 6, you must check that the permission is granted **before** you start using it. For example:

```
void requestLocationPermission() {

    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission. ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if ((permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Location activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission. ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 42);

    }
}
```

Read the doc for supporting runtime permissions to get the details.